# Remove specific characters from column data of select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, trim

I have searched and searched for a solution to my problem and even though I've found some that may help, I'm not sure it's the right way to do it for what I need. Keep in mind I am learning and fairly new to SQL. But I have two tables I want to query using an inner join.

There is a column named `CAVITY` in both tables but they hold the values in different formats. One table holds the value as H02 and the other table hold the value as just 2.

I want to inner join on this column using the H02 format but don't want to UPDATE the table that holds the value as a single number(for data entry purposes). So for example, if the one table column has H02 and the other has 2, I want it to be joined. If one table has H13 and the other 13, I want it to be a join as well. So basically, I am wanting to remove the H and 0 (but only if there is a 0 that directly follows the H). Unless there is a way to do the opposite and add the H / H0 from the results of the other table.

```
example data
table1.cavity   table2.cavity
     H01      =    1
     H02      =    2
     H10      =    10
     H12      =    12
```

It doesn't matter to me if my query results are the H0 version or not; I just need the joins to work; I can accommodate for either result in the end.

I am using SQL Server 2005

I have the rest of the query and it works ok; I just need this extra join added. Please help! Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED. Thank you

Comment: is `table2.cavity` of type `INT`?

Comment: Please go into more detail on the types of data you are trying to use for your join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REPLACE(REPLACE(cavity,'H0',''),'H','')`

The first removes H0:

`REPLACE(cavity,'H0','')`

And then the second replaces any remaining H's:

`REPLACE(output_of_previous,'H','')`

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I took so long to comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is as follows:

```
 from table1 join
      table2
      on cast(substring(table1.cavity, 2, 100) as int) = table2.cavity
```

(This is assuming the `2` means that table2.cavity is stored as an integer.

A big caution, though.  You need to pay attention to the query plan.  When writing such queries, it is quite easy to end up with a plan using a nested loop join.  If your tables are small, this isn't a big deal.  However, even moderately sized tables could produce a highly inefficient query plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar( 1000))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE PatIndex ('%[^0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
  SET @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp), 1, '')
  RETURN @Temp
END
```

It's possible use in join clause like this

```
SELECT a.col1 a, b.col1 b
FROM tablea a JOIN tableb b ON dbo.RemoveAlphaCharacters(a.col1) = b.col1
```